# How to get the id of the 'news_base' table?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

```
connection = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date now = new Date();
        String dateValue = simpleDateFormat.format(now);
        sql = "insert into news_base(fid,title,date,author) values("+fid+",'"+title+"','"+dateValue+"','Admin')";
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);

        sql1 = "insert into news_content (cid,fid,content) values("+cid+","+fid+",'"+content+"')";
        statement1 = connection.createStatement();
        statement1.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

The id of the 'news_base' is primary key and auto increment.
The id of the 'news_base' table is for the cid the 'news_content' table.

Comment: I am not working in Java but logically you can do this by getting last insert id of your first sql stmt and insert it to your sql1. you may find how to get last insert id in java.

Comment: I saw something about  LAST_INSERT_ID(), Lets check the link (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is it helpful for you or not

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :-

after `statement.executeUpdate(sql);` add this

```
ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rs.next())
{
     int your_id = rs.getInt(1);
}
```